# How can I hide an option in my drop down without changing the query

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, binding

I have a drop down in aspx that is binded using a class that has a function that retrieves a list of departments. There is a department Name "Audits and Verifying". I do not want to modify the query to do a `select Name, DepatmentValueName from departments where DepartmentValueName <>  'AuditsVerifying'` . Instead I want to hide it some how in the code in C# is this possible?

```
DepartmentsAdmin DepartmentName = new DepartmentsAdmin();
DepartmentType.DataSource = DepartmentName.GetAllDepartments();
DepartmentType.DataTextField = "Name";
DepartmentType.DataValueField = "DepartmentValueName";
DepartmentType.DataBind();
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
ListItem removeListItem = DepartmentType.Items.FindByText("Audits and Verifying");
DepartmentType.Items.Remove(removeListItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an item from your dropdownlist control after you bind to it.

```
DepartmentType.Items.Remove(DepartmentType.Items.FindByText("AuditsVerifying"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown.Items is an instance of a ListItemCollection. Below is an example of how to remove a ListItem from a ListItemCollection

```
ListItem myListItem = new ListItem(Delete.Text.ToLower(),Delete.Text.ToLower());
// Check whether the 'ListItem' is present in the 'ListBox' or not.
if(ItemCollection.Contains(myListItem))
{
   String deleteString=Delete.Text;
   // Delete the listitem entered by the user in textfield.
   ItemCollection.Remove(deleteString.ToLower());
   Message.Text="<font color='green'><b>Deleted Successfully</b></font>";
}
else
{
  Message.Text="<font color='red'><b>No ListItem with the given name is present in the ListBox for deletion.</b></font>";
}
```

Or you may remove an item based on the Text it displays by using:

```
DropDownList.Items.Remove("<your string that you want to remove>");
```

[ListItemCollection.Remove() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ef2fkzf.aspx)